# Oracle delete user

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have such table:

```
users:
id PK
.
.
.
```

```
workers:
id PK
user_id (FK to users)
.
.
.
```

```
evaluations:
id PK
worker_id (FK to workers)
.
.
.
```

And now I want to delete user. When I delete user then worker also should be deleted. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Create 3 delete-statements,
2. [Create a cascading delete constraint](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php).